# How to duplicate a record set spread over multiple tables in MSSQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a database which holds Quotations and Product Configurations, there is one header table for a Quotation under which there may be one or more Configurations. Within a configuration there are tables which define products and hardware in shades of one to one and one to many. If a customer wishes to alter any aspect of a quotation the current quotation must be frozen and another produced with a different quotation number. The quotation number is an auto ident field in the header table.

I wrote a long winded cloning script that worked at the start but as additional columns were required the cloning script quickly got out of date. This leaves sales support with the job of having to clone the quotation by hand which can often lead to mistakes.

How would you approach this in such a manner as to easily define the relationships, propogate the new id whilst not having to explicity specify all the columns in each table?

Comment: Do you *have* to clone the record, or can you implement a kind of change-tracking scheme instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can

```
SELECT * 
INTO #tableN
FROM tableN
WHERE QuotationID = @OldQuotationID
```

into temp tables for each of the tables involved, so that you don't have to know the exact schema of each table.  Then, after you've created the new header row and captured the new QuotationId value, you can update these tables with the new QuotationID and insert them back into the tables they came from.

Comment: I think this is a great plan. Except if any of the tables contains an IDENTITY column, it will be impossible to insert the rows back from the temporary counterpart without explicitly specifying the columns (and omitting the IDENTITY one).

Comment: Well, I think you could ALTER TABLE the temp tables to drop the identity columns.  So you'd have to know those by name, but not the rest.

Comment: Actually, that sounds plausible. Of course, if the OP insists on doing things the way they've described, that is. For the question in @Ic.'s comment makes sense too. Anyway, perhaps you'll want to consider incorporating somehow what you said in your comment into your answer, because it seems like the table in question does have an IDENTITY column (apparently I skimmed over the part where it says so when reading the question the first time), and in my opinion your addition is relevant enough to become part of the answer.

Comment: He wrote that "The quotation number is an auto ident field in the header table." so that's what I called the new QuotationID which can be picked up using SCOPE_IDENTITY() after inserting into the Quotation table.  If there were a more complete example in the problem, we could give a more complete answer.   I hate to guess about the complexities that may or may not arise.

Comment: I think I can now see where I was misunderstanding your answer. For some reason I thought that your example was about duplicating the header row itself (the one in the Quotations table and having QuotationID as its primary key too). That's why I thought your answer was incomplete, because inserting the contents of the temp table back to the original table would be impossible without explicitly specifying the columns (to omit QuotationID). But you probably meant to show how to duplicate a *dependent* table's row (where QuotationID is a foreign key), didn't you? Makes more sense to me that way.

Comment: Yes, maybe I should have been clearer.  The real problem seemed to me to be how to "propagate the new id" into the dependent tables without having to hard-code the schema for each of the columns (as that changes over time).